# Django serializer send array in object

Tags: python, django, model, django-rest-framework, serialization

I have models like this:

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Model2(models.Model):

    model1= models.ForeignKey(Model1, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="my_list")
    f1 = models.FloatField()
```

I want to create endpoint for send data like this:

> {"time":"123", "my_list":[{"f1":"123"}, {"f1":"123"}, {"f1":"123"}]}

This is my serializer

```
class TestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):


 class Meta:
        model = Model1
        fields = ('id',
                  'time',
                  'my_list',)
```

How i can send json like i want? (

```
{"time":"123", "my_list":[{"f1":"123"}, {"f1":"123"}, {"f1":"123"}]}
```

)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [**`ListField`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#listfield) along with [**`DictField`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#dictfield) as **`child`**

```
class TestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    my_list = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.DictField())
    class Meta:
        model = Model1
        fields = ('id', 'time', 'my_list',)
```

Comment: Depending on how complex the objects in your list are, you may want to set `child=serializers.JSONField` .